# Agregar items a json

Tags: json, kotlin

Como puedo agregar un item a este json? de esta manera lo podre recibir en la activity de detalles para completar una url para acceder a ella.

```
[
    {           
        "item1": "Finalizado",
        "item2": "F"
}]
```

Y mi intencion es agregar "item3": "$dato" despues de "item2": "F"
El $dato puede ser 1, 2, 3, que es un string el cual sera el valor que me devuelva la variable *dato* y esto es lo que hago:

```
val jorn = items.add(dato) // dato en rojo

val adapter = AdapJor(activity !!, jorn ) //jorn en rojo

private fun requestJsonObject() {

    val queue = newRequestQueue(activity)

    val url = Directions.JORNADAS + Directions.CMP + "&jor=$dato&tmp=" + Directions.TMP

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->

        val builder = GsonBuilder()
        val mGson = builder.create()

        var items: List<ModelJor>

        items = Arrays.asList(*mGson.fromJson(response, Array<ModelJor>::class.java))

        val jorn = items.add(dato)

        recyclerView !!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)

        val adapter = AdapJor(activity !!, jorn )
        recyclerView !!.adapter = adapter

    }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.message) })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Comment: Hola podrias especificar que item? cual json? y donde esta el error?

Comment: Post 1 editado con el json